# CKeditor replacing HTML on load

Tags: html, css, ckeditor

I have an instance of CKEditor running to edit small parts of a website. The original HTML is:

```
  <div class="slide slideleft">
      <a href="#" class="slidelefta">
          <img src="img/left.png" alt="previous" />
      </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide slidemid noauto" style="height: auto; text-align: center;">
    <a href="#" class="sliderighta">
        <img src="img/main_item.png" alt="item" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide slideright">
      <a href="#" class="sliderighta">
          <img src="img/right.png" alt="next" />
      </a>
  </div>
```

now, when I load it into CKEdit (inside a `<textarea>`, all correctly encoded with PHP's htmlspecialchars() method), it replaces all my carefully crafted DIVs and styles with the following:

```
<p><a href="#"><img alt="previous" src="img/left.png" /></a></p>
<p><a href="#"><img alt="burg.ring1" src="img/main_item.png" /></a></p>
<p><a href="#"><img alt="next" src="img/right.png" /></a></p>
```

which of course totally ruins the page's layout. Can CKEditor somehow be set to **not** do that?

Thank you!

Comment: how are you loading ckeditor? what is your ckeditor config? what is your ckeditor version?

Comment: it's a default install (v. 4.1), no changes to the config. loaded exactly as described on their "integration" page (CKEDITOR.replace('editor') in document.ready()), the textarea code is: `<textarea name="editor">'.htmlspecialchars($html).'</textarea>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since CKEditor 4.1 the Advanced Content Filter feature is enabled. You need to configure it in order to have your HTML passing the validation. See my previous answer here: [CKEditor strips inline attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753956/ckeditor-strips-inline-attributes/15758342#15758342).