# ckeditor h1 getting filtered

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I'm using the latest ckeditor v4.1 and I'm having this issue where my h1 tag gets removed by the editor.
my code:

```
editor.setData(html);
```

the original markup is:

```
<h1>header</h1>
hello world!
```

it will be changed to:

```
header<br>
hello world!
```

any tips to disable this kind of filtering?

Comment: This issue has been already explained in the past  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753956/ckeditor-strips-inline-attributes/15758342#15758342

Comment: thanks .. couldnt find it @stackoverflow..