# ckeditor stripping code down

Tags: html, ckeditor, editing

I have a code that should look like that:

```
<div class="menuslct">
  <table width="980" border="0" style="text-align:center">
    <tbody><tr>
      <td width="33%"><a href="/en/education"><img src="/common/img/icons/01 online.PNG" name="online" width="81" height="78"></a></td>
      <td width="33%"><a href="http://esukhia.org/en/education/immersion"><img src="/common/img/icons/02 immersion.jpg" name="immersion" width="80" height="78"></a></td>
      <td width="33%"><a href="http://esukhia.org/en/education/thesisadv"><img src="/common/img/icons/03 Thesis Advisor.jpg" width="78" name="thesisadv" height="78"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="33%" name="online">Online</td>
      <td width="33%" name="immersion">Immersion</td>
      <td width="33%" name="thesisadv">Research Advisor</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody></table>
</div>
```

but instead when opened in ckeditor via a php include:

```
<textarea name="editor1" id="editor1">
      <?php echo file_get_contents('education.php');?>
    </textarea>
        <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
        </script>
```

it looks like this:

```
<div class="menuslct">
<table border="0" style="text-align:center; width:980px">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/en/education"><img src="/common/img/icons/01 onlie.PNG" style="height:78px; width:81px" /></a></td>
        <td><a href="http://esukhia.org/en/education/immersion"><img src="/common/img/icons/02 immersion.jpg" style="height:78px; width:80px" /></a></td>
        <td><a href="http://esukhia.org/en/education/thesisadv"><img src="/common/img/icons/03 Thesis Advisor.jpg" style="height:78px; width:78px" /></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Online</td>
        <td>Immersion</td>
        <td>Research Advisor</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

why is ckeditor stripping my code like that??

Comment: You should take a look on [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) guide. You'll need to configure that feature.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ckeditor strips inline attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753956/ckeditor-strips-inline-attributes)

Comment: well I tried adding this `config.extraAllowedContent = 'td{*}';` to the config.js but it didn't change anything...(solution that I found here http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/Allow-inline-style-with-Advanced-Content-Filter )

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by invoking this ckeditor this way:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',{allowedContent: true} );
```

this remove all ckeditor stripping features.

Comment: You should've used `td[width]` instead of `td{*}` when defining `config.extraAllowedContent`. Width is not a style but an attribute. There's no need to disable the whole feature as it's to protect your HTML from garbage and dirty stuff.