# CKEditor removing inline CSS

Tags: css, asp.net, ckeditor

It might sound like a duplicate of a lot of questions, but what differs in this is that I am building a mail body in CKEditor where I must apply `inline-css` as I don't have `class` in the user's mailbox.

I am applying `inline-css` but that is removed automatically by CKEditor. Any solution or suggestion for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ckeditor strips inline attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753956/ckeditor-strips-inline-attributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not have configured the allowed content.

see: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.feature-property-allowedContent