# CSS not recognizing id or name

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor

I'm developing a flask application and i'm trying to change the content inside of my textarea(see textarea tag below). I'm using an opensource web text editor called ckeditor. My issue is that when I try to style the stuff found in the p tag using the id name "name1" it won't actually style it. However when I use the just use p tag itself it works fine.  I'm new at developing web applications and any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Here is a snippet of the code:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <form>
        <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="20" cols="70">

            <p id = "name1">  [Your Name]<p>

        </textarea>
        <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
            CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = '../static/startpage.css';
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
 #name1{ 
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight:  lighter;
    font-size: 18px;  
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Here is the snippet of CSS code that works but is not what I want:

```
 p{ 
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight:  lighter;
    font-size: 18px;  
    padding-left: 20px;
 }
```

Comment: have you check if the name of the tag p is name1 after rendering

Comment: your p-tag will be rendered as text in normal textarea. You're replacing it with the ckeditor. seems to be that the editor remove ids from the html tags... check in developer tools if the p-tag has the id, you expect

Comment: @Mephiztopheles yes you are right! ckeditor removes ids and classes automatically. thank you so much, i would give you an upvote if this wasn't just a comment

Comment: I can send this as Answer :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [CKEditor strips inline attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753956/ckeditor-strips-inline-attributes)

Comment: Yes, this is a DUP of questions related to the ACF. This one has the best answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659390/ckeditor-automatically-strips-classes-from-div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your p-tag will be rendered as text in normal textarea.
You're replacing it with the `CKEDITOR`.
`CKEDITOR` will automatically remove ids and classes from html-tags

Answer (score 0):

Content within `<textarea>` will NOT be parse as HTML by the browser. So, literally it's not HTML at all, it's just **plain text** that represents HTML snippet.

You should use other tags as its container, e.g. `<div>` or whatever.

```
<div><p id="name1">[Your Name]<p></div>
```

EDIT: I noticed that you are using CKEditor. From your code I guess you are trying to place some default rich text within the editor. So I assume the root cause is either (1) you are not following the doc, or (2) there's error initiating the editor.

Answer (score 0):

As akash pointed out we cannot insert other html tags inside the textarea since it is a input tag. To display some text with in input tags you can use placeholder, other option is in-field(you can google this if you want to use this) labels

below is the code using place holder

```
 <form>
        <textarea placeholder="[Your Name]" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
 </form>
```

you can style the placeholder like below

```
::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight:  lighter;
    font-size: 18px;  
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Note: the above css only works for mozilla. please follow below link for make it work with other browsers

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/

Hope this helps