# ckeditor 4.7.0 remove style attribute

Tags: php, html, ckeditor, strip-tags

i read more article about how to allow ckeditor to accept all attribute and how to fix it, but still i have problem. ckeditor remove style attribute.
i try to justify text or change color ,....;

here is what i do:

**ckeditor/config.js**

```
/**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2017, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.md or http://ckeditor.com/license
 */

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.allowedContent = true;
    config.extraAllowedContent = 'style;*[id,rel](*){*}';//
    config.removeFormatAttributes = '';
};
```

but when i insert data into database i see:

```
<p [removed] center;">
```

i read [[CKEditor strips inline attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753956/ckeditor-strips-inline-attributes][1])

[1]: [CKEditor strips inline attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753956/ckeditor-strips-inline-attributes]) and to more option like `config.extraAllowedContent = '*{*}';` but still no luck.

any suggestion ?