# CKEditor removes class attribute from table

Tags: html, css, ckeditor

In my `<textarea>`, I have this text:

```
<table class='table table-striped'>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

After using `CKEDITOR.replace()`, my text area become a CKEditor and it has a table in it. The problem is CKEditor adds its class to my table called `cke_show_border`. Only attributes in that class are applied to the table, none of my class is applied.

What should I do to make it apply my `table` and `table-striped` class?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: if you send this code from CKE to database you will have the table with your class and css will be applied as well. Never tried applying custom css to html tags inside CKE tho

Comment: What do you mean by saying "send this code from CKE to database"? I just try to display it to users.

Comment: I thought you are going to use it in some php application

Comment: No, I use ASP.NET MVC 4 :)

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue where opening and saving with CKEditor 7.x.1.13 in Drupal 7 was stripping out attributes in my HTML elements. Adding the following under "Custom JavaScript configuration" fixed it.

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

Answer (score 9):

You can allow anything: tags, classes, styles and attributes by setting

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

However, better is to allow only features you need additionally to what is provided with plugins.
To allow any class to be attached to a table, type

```
config.extraAllowedContent = 'table(*)';
```

To read more about rules syntax go here: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules-section-string-format

Answer (score 5):

As I see here, most likely you're using CKEditor 4.1 or newer and your problem is [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter). I guess that there's no "Advanced" tab in your table dialog as well as no `dialogadvtab` plugin in your editor package:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.yourInstance.plugins.dialogadvtab
> undefined
```

Right? Then you got to configure `config.extraAllowedContent`:

```
config.extraAllowedContent = `table[class]`;
```

Why is it so, you may ask? This is because there's no [feature](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.feature) (command, button, dialog, field, etc.) in the editor that appends classes to `<table>` tags. So there's no feature that says:

> "Hey, editor, I'm gonna add classes to tables, and you should be cool with it."

In fact, this is done by defining [allowedContent](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.feature-property-allowedContent) along with feature definition. So if there's no `dialogadvtab` plugin loaded that would tell the editor that tables can go with classes, editor discards `class` attributes on the output as they are not supported by any feature.

This behavior is to keep your markup clean and take the control of what is produced by your WYSIWYG editor. Still, it needs attention and basic understanding.

See my previous answer to the similar question: [CKEditor automatically strips classes from div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659390/ckeditor-removing-div-classes/15662539#15662539)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my `dialogadvtab` is existed. Besides, CKE doesn't remove my class, it's still there but it's not applied.

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution.

This turns off the filtering, it's working, but not a good idea...

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

To play with a content string works fine for id, etc, but not for the class and style attributes, because you have () and {} for class and style filtering.

So my bet is for allowing any class in the editor is:

```
config.extraAllowedContent = '*(*)';
```

This allows any class and any inline style.

```
config.extraAllowedContent = '*(*);*{*}';
```

To allow only class="asdf1" and  class="asdf2" for any tag:

```
config.extraAllowedContent = '*(asdf1,asdf2)';
```

(so you have to specify the classnames)

To allow only class="asdf" only for p tag:

```
config.extraAllowedContent = 'p(asdf)';
```

To allow id attribute for any tag:

```
config.extraAllowedContent = '*[id]';
```

etc etc

To allow style tag (<style type="text/css">...</style>):

```
config.extraAllowedContent = 'style';
```

To be a bit more complex:

```
config.extraAllowedContent = 'span;ul;li;table;td;style;*[id];*(*);*{*}';
```

Hope it's a better solution...

Comment: This is not what the question was about.

Answer (score 1):

Thsi is the perfect example to use CKeditor  4.0 and higher version with our own css style.

```
  <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.9/standard-all/ckeditor.js"></script>



     var editor = CKEDITOR.replace("textarea", {
                        width: 750, height: 500, fullPage: true,
                        extraPlugins: 'stylesheetparser',

                        //// Do not load the default Styles configuration.
                        stylesSet: [],
                        on: {
                            instanceReady: function (evt) {
                            // Remove ckeditor table border
                            $("iframe").contents().find('body').removeClass('cke_show_borders');
                          }
                       }

                    });
```

Comment: There is another option for hiding table borders by configuring property : config.startupShowBorders = false;

Answer (score 0):

Add border=1 to the table and that way CKEditor won't set its own class on the table
(there might be other ways to do it, but I always found this the easier as it doesn't requires any change to CKEditor)

Comment: Yes, but it still doesn't apply my CSS class.

Comment: You might have forgotten to add the css to the contents of the editor, or there's some other rule with higher priority. At this point we can only guess what's your problem.

Comment: No rule with higher priority here, I've checked it using Inspect Element of FireFox. Do I have to put the CSS to my text area, too? But the users will see the CSS in the editor? I store my CSS in a CSS file.

Comment: Have you adjusted the value of the contentsCss config value to your CSS file?

Comment: What's that? How to adjust it?

Answer (score 0):

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

I fixed the same issue by adding this code on localhost. But on my server it did not work. Thank to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967092/ckeditor-4-2-2-allowedcontent-true-is-not-working), I disabled `'tabletools' : 1,` in ckeditor/build-config.js and it helped.

Answer (score 0):

And Still, in 2020, The problems occur to many users,
for solution follow the step

1.goto ckeditor folder

2.find file **config.js** and open it

3.find

```
`config.extraAllowedContent = 'div(*)'`;
```

Add `table(*)` like this

```
`config.extraAllowedContent = 'table(*);div(*)';`
```

**note** if you don't find point no 3 then add the following code to config.js file

```
`config.div_wrapTable = true;` 


`config.extraAllowedContent = 'table(*);`
```