# CKEditor 4.2.2 - allowedContent = true is not working

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, config

I guess I've read most of the SO questions and CKEditor documentation about this, but it does not work for me.

It should be plain and simple, in my CKEditor config.js, I have this :

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
    config.allowedContent = true;
};
```

But the html is still filtered and this piece of code is being stripped :

```
<p>
<a href="/site/public/press.pdf"><span class="icon-presseFile"></span></a>
<a href="/site/public/pics.zip"><span class="icon-pressePics"></span></a>
</p>
```

into this :

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

The `<span>` elements are font icons.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

***EDIT***
It works if I add some text in the `<span>` elements (but I don't want tohave to do that)

Comment: The issue is propably not with ACF. That's what it does, empty `span`, `i`, `b` and `a` are all removed. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261198 for solution or use something that is not a span. Or add &nbsp;. Or wait for the new widgets feature, which I think might be very good for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ckeditor removing empty span automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261198/ckeditor-removing-empty-span-automatically)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found that I had to add it OUTSIDE of the main config function.

This worked:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
...
};
CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
```

But this didn't:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.allowedContent = true;
    ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In fact, my problem was elsewhere, but it's good to know anyway!

Comment: I have the same problem but this is not working for me. Did you figure out any other solutions to this ?

Answer (score 7):

Be aware that it might be a rogue plugin causing config.allowedContent = true to be ignored. [I just learned this at a cost of 12 hours of my life](http://ckeditor.com/addon/widgetbootstrap).

The offending plugin overrode config.allowedContent = true in the custom config file. So if you're banging your head against the wall cursing at CKEditor, try disabling/commenting out all of your plugins (config.extraPlugins). If the problem goes away, you know one of those plugins is the cause.

Answer (score 1):

This solution helped me solved my problem : [CKEditor strips <i> Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250404/ckeditor-strips-i-tag)

For the span I wrote in the config.js :

```
// ALLOW <span></span>
config.protectedSource.push( /<span[\s\S]*?\>/g ); //allows beginning <span> tag
config.protectedSource.push( /<\/span[\s\S]*?\>/g ); //allows ending </span> tag
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Firefox. 
To solve it I had to change the name of the config.js file to anything else like ckeConfig.js and declare the new name:

```
CKEDITOR.replace("textAreaId", {
    customConfig: 'yourPath/ckeditor/ckeConfig.js', 
});
```

And don't forget to link in Html too:

```
<script src="~/yourPath/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="~/yourPath/ckeditor/ckeConfig.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
CKEDITOR.replace('instanceName', { extraAllowedContent: 'a span' });

You can put whatever tags in that extraAllowedContent string that you do not want it to alter.

Comment: What if you don't want to alter ANYTHING and leave <h4> and <article> and <span> and anything else alone?

Comment: This was a while ago, but from what I remember there were some tags that were not altered at all.  I am pretty sure CKEditor will always alter your html, no matter what you do.  If that is not true, I would love someone to tell me how to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

adding this into the CKEDITOR.editorConfig function did it for me:

config.allowedContent = true;
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty = false;