# CKEditor allowerContent = true simply not working for me

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor4.x

I am using CKEditor 4.5 and I want to disable the html formatting when I save. I just need to save the html. To do this in CKEditor, there is a setting needed to set this as true.

```
CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
```

I did this in CK editor config.js file as shown below.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    config.allowedContent = true;
};
```

This is not working for me. I tried [CKEditor 4.2.2 - allowedContent = true is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967092/ckeditor-4-2-2-allowedcontent-true-is-not-working) but it is still not working.

Can someone give me an exact example or any other way to fix this. I simply do not want this editor to correct my HTML and I want to save it.

Comment: May you share more code html and js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. It was simply not refreshing the browser cache.

You always need to refresh the cache and clean history to make changes effective.