# Preserve styling for text created by CK Editor in Rails

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

I have successfully integrated CK Editor in my Rails 4 app through [galetahub/ckeditor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) gem. I use CK Editor in my app to create a Post which is a model. CK Editor works fine while creating the post but after creating the text is shown as plain html code and not as the styled one which I created through CK Editor.

posts/new.html.erb

```
 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br>
    <%= f.cktext_area :content %>
 </div>
```

posts/show.html.erb

```
<p>
  <strong>Content:</strong>
  <%= @post.content %>
</p>
```

I have also tired `raw(@post.content)` and `@post.content.html_safe` but the blockquote are not appearing as it is when created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CKEditor is known as a [WYSIWYG editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG), which means it stores pure HTML in your DB

There are two issues which your system may have:

1. CKEditor is not saving the HTML to your database correctly
2. You're not calling the HTML code correctly in your app

---

**DB**

I would start by looking into the database -- is your CKEditor saving the HTML?

In your `posts` / `content` column, you should have a series of records with valid html syntax. If not, your problem will be with how you're saving the data from your CKEditor

---

**View**

`raw()` and `.html_safe` basically process the Rails variables as actual HTML (meaning `<p>` will be rendered as a paragraph etc)

If you're seeing the code outputted "naked" (you can just see `<p>` etc), I would imagine the problem would be with the type of code you're submitting (you mentioned blockquotes)

Could you update us with the code that's being outputted?

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor will filter the inline-style and javascript by default.

The easiest solution is going to the config.js and setting:

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

refer to: [CKEditor automatically strips classes from div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659390/ckeditor-automatically-strips-classes-from-div/15659962#15659962)