# WYSIWYG Ckeditor is removing several html tags

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

Recently i am having a problem with CKeditor.

Integrated it very well into a custom CMS, however it seems to be stripping certain tags. Most importantly : `'data-toggle'`, `'data-target'` and all of the `font-awesom`e css classes.

Given I am using bootstrap for the templating engine, is there any resaon ,why this is happening.

Example :

```
<a class="btn btn-block btn-inverse" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#downloadModal" href="#">Download Trial</a>
```

Becomes:

```
<a class="btn btn-block btn-inverse" href="#">Download Trial</a>
```

Is there a set of HTML defined tags in CKeditor i could add to ? Or another editor which will play nicer ?

Comment: Why was my post edited with spelling errors and grammatical mistakes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your config.js file you can prevent any stripping by using the flag

```
    config.allowedContent = true;
```

Reference : http://ckeditor.com/ckeditor_4.3_beta/samples/datafiltering.html

Similar question concerning CSS Classes: [CKEditor automatically strips classes from div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659390/ckeditor-automatically-strips-classes-from-div)

For added advice often the ckEditor will infact still strip certain tags out. If this is happening you can add the following again to your `config.js` file.

```
extraAllowedContent: 'data-toggle[*]{*}'
```