# CKEditor Stylesheet in document

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

We are offering our customers a HTML editor to adjust their email templates. However some email templates have a custom stylesheet at the top.

Something linke this:

```
<style type="text/css">

div, p, a, li, td { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; text-decoration:none;}
@font-face {font-family: 'elegible_nova_rgbold_italic';src: url('http://sub.example.com/mailing/defaultFiles/elegiblenova-boldit-webfont.eot');src: url('http://sub.example.com/mailing/defaultFiles/elegiblenova-boldit-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('http://sub.example.com/mailing/defaultFiles/elegiblenova-boldit-webfont.woff') format('woff'),url('http://sub.example.com/mailing/defaultFiles/elegiblenova-boldit-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;}
</style>
```

However, when this is loaded into the CKEditor the CSS isn't in the source of the document. How can make sure the CSS is in the "text area" and will outputted as well?

I'm using creditor 3.0

Comment: I've only used ckeditor 4.x, but have you tried something along these lines? `config.format_style = { element : 'style', attributes : { 'type' : 'text/css' } };`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain because I haven't used CKEditor for several years, but I believe you need to [allow this content specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15659962/632736). CKEditor 4 goes further and strips even more stuff out and requires an additional setting to be configured.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`config.contentsCss`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-contentsCss) to insert additional styles into CKEditor editing area. [Classic CKEditor](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_framed) is based on `<iframe>` and it won't apply global styles of the web page to the content, unless you specify them that way.

- [More about styles](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_styles)
- [Even more about styles](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_howtos_styles)