# width=100% is being stripped while opening saved CK editor data

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor

I saved CKeditor content

`<img width="100%" src="image.png"/>`

in mysql db , when I reopen it in Html  form   i.e[Ckeditor field]

content I got is

```
<img  src="image.png"/>
```

The problem is

width="100%" is being ripped off.

How to retrieve original content without losing any data being ripped off.

Comment: Please show us your javascript CKeditor initialization. Also, [this might be helpful](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules).

Comment: `width="100%"` is not valid HTML: The value of the width must be in pixels and not percentage. That's probably the reason why it is stripped off the code, you may be able to disable the HTML validation in the editor, but I've never worked with CKEditor so I can't tell.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Any documentation of that? According to the [MDN](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/HTML/Element/img.html), the `width` attribute of an `<img>` tag is defined as `The width of the image in pixels or percent.`

Comment: @showdev Good question. If I check `<img src="mypic" alt="" width="50%" />` on the W3 Markup Validation Service (with doctype HTML5 and an empty page), it fails stating "Bad value 50% for attribute width on element img: Expected a digit but saw % instead". Here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/img.html it specifies that it has to be a non-negative integer in CSS pixels

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Great, thanks! Looks like the MDN could use an update for the `width` attribute in HTML5.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ckeditor automatically strips classes from div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659390/ckeditor-automatically-strips-classes-from-div)