# CKEditor changing all my HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor, accordion

I have been struggling with CKEditor the whole day long. All because it is re-formatting all my HTML. For some reason, it replaces tags like `<dl>` for `<div>` or `<p>`. So, I took [this plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/htmlbuttons?page=1) and changed the HTML output of one of the predefined buttons into:

```
<dl class="accordion" data-accordion>
    <dd class="accordion-navigation"> 
      <a href="#panel1">Redigera sidor</a> 
        <div id="panel1" class="content"> 
          <a href="edit_index.php" title="Redigera startsidan">Redigera startsidan</a>
        </div> 
    </dd> 
</dl>
```

More info about this code block [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/accordion.html).

When I press the button, CKEditor outputs the following code:

```
<p><a href="#panel1">Redigera sidor</a></p>

<div class="content"><a href="edit_index.php">Redigera startsidan</a></div>

<p><a href="#panel2">Inst&auml;llningar</a></p>

<div class="content"><a href="memberlist.php">Administrat&ouml;rer lista</a></div>
```

I cannot understand why is this happening. I am using CKEditor 4.3.2 with Foundation 5.

**UPDATE**

I have tried to use this plugin instead: http://ckeditor.com/addon/templates and change the HTML of one of the templates to:

```
{
        title: 'Ny radioprogram',
        image: 'template2.gif',
        description: 'A template that defines two colums, each one with a title, and some text.',
        html: '<div class="row">' +
                   '<div class="small-2 large-4 columns"><p>Skriv titeln och infoga din Youtube radioprogram</p></div>' +
               '</div>'
    },
```

The result is the same, CKEditor is still outputting the wrong code. This is the output:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>Skriv titeln och infoga din Youtube radioprogram</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

I guess I have strong evidence that something is not ok with my CKEditor. Any clues?

Comment: Well that code is not valid HTML. Where is the dt?

Comment: Sorry, dt? What is that? And which code is not valid? If you are referring to the accordion code, I took it from Foundation 5. I have the link on the post.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl

Comment: Interesting, how come isn't the code valid if it is being distributed with F5? Anyway, the final result is the same, read my update on the question. So, the issue cannot be the lack of a <dt>...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ckeditor automatically strips classes from div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659390/ckeditor-automatically-strips-classes-from-div)

Comment: @Reinmar That actually helped me a lot! I found the answer right there and I regret that I didn't find it directly when I searched for answers. It turns out that I had to use a solution like the one explained on the first answer. Something like `config.extraAllowedContent = 'div(col-md-*,container-fluid,row)';` Many, many thanks!!

Comment: Cool :). I rewrote yesterday the most popular answer to that question, so it's showcasing more than just one of the options.

Answer (score 0):

Read about the [Content Filtering](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf). There are many ways to configure CKEditor's content filtering mechanism (called the [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter)) so I can't just show here once, because that would be misleading.

**Update:** Clear your browsers cache after changing any configuration option.

Comment: Just added config.allowedContent = true; but the result is still the same :/

Comment: Dozens of variations of this question has been answered on SO dozens of times and that's why we created that document. There's no single answer, because there's many configuration options that can be used, that's why I linked to the documentation instead of giving some misleading, simplified answer. But I guess that I need to ask a generalised question one day, copy the answer from the documentation I created, and then close all other questions as duplicates.

Comment: The browser's cache has nothing to do with this in this particular case, because usually that is the number one thing I take care of  when I have issues. I did a search before I posted this question but could not find anything similar @Reinmar. Since you say you have answered so many times to this question, do you think you can link me to some? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You know what @Reinmar? I found the answer in the link you provided on my first post. Cheers! :)