# How to show HTML formatted text in CKeditor RTE V4.4.5 when no toolbar icons present ? Used to work in V3.5..?

Tags: ckeditor

I have configured a no toolbar and ReadOnly instance of CKEditor to show formatted HTML on a web page.

This was working well with V3.5 of CKEditor with:

```
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      $('.CKEditorRTE').ckeditor(function () { }, { readOnly: true, toolbar: 'ReadOnly',toolbarStartupExpanded: false, toolbarCanCollapse: false, toolbar_Custom: [],uiColor: '#edeff1', resize_minHeight : 100, height: 125, resize_minWidth : 100, width: 600 })
   </script>
```

With V4.4.5 The formatting goes, unless I put the following in the "Config.js"

```
config.toolbar_ReadOnly = [{items: ['Format']}];
```

Now I actually do not want this format icon, but I do want the preformatted text. So how can I have preformatted HTML text with no toolbar icons with CKEditor 4.4.5 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ckeditor automatically strips classes from div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659390/ckeditor-automatically-strips-classes-from-div)

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659390/ckeditor-automatically-strips-classes-from-div. The title of the question is different, but it's the same CKEditor feature - just different tags.

Comment: HI, Thanks so far. I am not sure I understand how this is a duplicate as the other question talks about "config.allowedContent = true;" while my question is not about text entry and messing with the content, but rather about not displaing it in a "wysiwyg" way ie including all the HTML formatting. If I add the "Format" icon in then I get all the formatting back, so the content is not changed by CKEditor, it is just the display of it, via a ReadOnly configured RTE, is compromised to allow only standard text. It is the same effect when say a CSS becomes unlinked... all the formatting goes.

Comment: OK, having now tested it, the suggestion has worked, which puzzles me as I was displaying, but it works so I am happy. Thanks. I can mark an answer if provided.