# Ckeditor | Page source code is not loading properly

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Ckeditor automatically stripping classes/styles/tags when I add the source code of this page into the editor:  view-source:http://islandworkshop.myinstapage.com/ ... which results in bad page structure.

But when I enter the same source code in Jsbin.com's HTML window then it works like a charm. I thought Ckeditor is behaving like this because of its "Advanced Content Filter". So I tried “**allowedContent: true**” and "**config.extraAllowedContent = '*(*);*{*}';**" but for no luck :(

According to CKEditor: "Ckeditor uses advanced W3C DTD controls to ensure that HTML is properly generated. Users will not enter broken code so your pages will easily validate."

Well, I don't think I'm entering broken codes but still pages are not loading properly. Please help.

Comment: allowedContent: true

Comment: possible duplicate of [CKEditor automatically strips classes from div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659390/ckeditor-automatically-strips-classes-from-div)

Answer (score 0):

allowedContent: true
should solve it
I had problems because the config file was cached in the browser.
try reloading it manually in the browser (Ctrl+F5).