# separate ckeditor template for each page

Tags: ckeditor, fckeditor

I want to have separate config for ckditor.

For example in page `temp1.html` i want to have 'links' and in page `temp2.html` i don't  want to have `links`.

Whats the good config for this?

I think `configuration` in below code is proper place for do this.

```
    //var editor_data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
    $('textarea#editor').ckeditor(
    function () {
        /* callback code */
    },
    //configuration
    {
        toolbar: 'Basic',
        language: 'en',
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`config.removePlugins`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-removePlugins) to control the presence of certain plugins, like link (also `config.removeButtons`). But please note that since CKEditor 4.1, by doing this you [restrict the content](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) of the editor associated with the plugin or button (no link plugin or button = no links in the content).

So if you want to share the same content between different templates which use a different sets of plugins you need to explicitly expand [`config.extraAllowedContent`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraAllowedContent) of some editors:

```
$('#editor-linkless').ckeditor( function() {}, {
    removePlugins: 'link',
    extraAllowedContent: 'a[href,name,id,target]'
} );

$('#editor-regular').ckeditor();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/ngwqqrba/).

See the official [guide](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/acf.html) about ACF. Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15659962/1485219) to know more.