# ckeditor with no toolbar with bootstrap and display Preview by external button in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor

I am about to use `CKEditor` for `post` functionality. But I don't need a toolbar for the `post` functionality. I need to provide a `preview` of the `post` that should be `HTML` version, `preview` functionality should be done by `onkeyup`/`any button`. And `preview` section will be below the `CKEditor`.

**Image** http://grab.by/H5Sk

The mail purpose is to provide a formatted post to the `user`. If I am using `textarea` then it returns a `string` and I can not display as `user` entered in textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`editor#change`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-change) and [`editor#contentDom`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-contentDom) events. You **should not** disable the toolbar like

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {toolbar: []})
```

because it will disallow any type type of the content in your editor as the [toolbar corresponds with Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter), unless you disable it by setting `config.allowedContent = true`, which is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15659962/1485219).

See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/tjbjrowm/).

HTML

```
<textarea id="editor">
    <p>Hello world! <a href="http://google.com">This is some link</a>.</p>
    <p>And there is some <s>deleted</s>&nbsp;text.</p>
</textarea>    

<div id="preview"></div>
```

JS

```
var preview = CKEDITOR.document.getById( 'preview' );

function syncPreview() {
    preview.setHtml( editor.getData() );
}

var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    on: {
        // Synchronize the preview on user action that changes the content.
        change: syncPreview,

        // Synchronize the preview when the new data is set.
        contentDom: syncPreview
    }
} );
```

CSS

```
/* Hide the toolbar with CSS */
.cke_top { display: none !important }
```

Answer (score 0):

For ckeditor:
Test

CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {toolbar: []});

Another solution:

[This is What Stackoverflow is using](https://code.google.com/p/wmd/)