# How can I add JavaScript in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am creating on form in CKEditor. In this form, there is one input in which if I enter DOB birth then in second read only textbox it should give Age.

Now, I know the script of this age calculation but when i try to add this function of age calculation into CKEditor window it rip-out. So, how can i add `<script>` tag in this form?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CKEditor automatically strips classes from div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659390/ckeditor-automatically-strips-classes-from-div)

Comment: Although it may not look like that, this question can be generalised to "why CKEditor removes <script> tags" and then it's a clear DUP of the mentioned question.