# Add a <div> inside CKEditor without embedding a <div> button on toolbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor, editor

I wanna configure CKEditor, like it should have a div inside the input area. As shown below in image, but i wanna remove the `div button` (That i marked in image) from toolbar.
[image]

my code is here:

```
<form>
       <textarea id="contents" name="contents">
            &lt;div id=&quot;mydiv&quot; style=&quot;border:1px solid red;margin: 0 auto;width:780px;height:1200px;margin-top:-18px;&quot;&gt; my div &lt;/div&gt;
        </textarea>

         <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.1/full/ckeditor.js"></script>
        <script>

     var Editor   =   CKEDITOR.replace( 'contents', {uiColor: '#88aa22'});
            Editor.config.toolbar = [
                {name: 'first', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Find', 'Replace']},
                {name: 'second', items: ['SelectAll', 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo']},
                {name: 'therd', items: ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock']},
                {name: 'forth', items: ['Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList']},
                {name: 'fifth', items: ['Blockquote','HorizontalRule','Maximize', 'Preview']},
                '/',
                {name: 'last', items: ['Font', 'FontSize', 'Styles', 'Format','CreateDiv']}
            ];
             Editor.config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;
             function Send(){
             var data = CKEDITOR.instances.contents.getData();
             alert(data);
         }
        </script>

</form>
```

Fiddle i have created for you is here: https://jsfiddle.net/t4jmo09g/

the result i want :
[image]

I am trying to create a page like environment inside editor.

What should i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could exclude `'CreateDiv'` from `config.toolbar` and then define `config.extraAllowedContent = 'div[dir,id,lang,title](*){*}'` to allow divs of any class, any style but with limited set of attributes, which is default configuration of [Div](http://ckeditor.com/addon/div) plugin.

`extraAllowedContent` is necessary because since CKEditor 4.1.x features correspond to editable content. So if you remove the feature from the toolbar, you also tell the editor to purge associated types of content (html). Simply – no Div plugin, no `<div>` in the content.

But If I were you I'd probably get rid of the plugin completely with `config.removePlugins = 'div'` and then just play with `config.extraAllowedContent` because there's no sense in loading a plugin you don't use.

Read more about [`config.extraAllowedContent`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraAllowedContent), [`config.removePlugins`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-removePlugins) and [common problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15659962/1485219) with content filtering. There's also an [official guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) about Advanced Content Filter in CKEditor.

Comment: what the mean of this expiration `div[dir,id,lang,title](*){*}` please tell me.

Comment: @G4uKu3_Gaurav See [this](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules) guide.

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you are trying to do something that can be easily done using shared space?

http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/sharedspace.html

You can have long toolbar and bottom bar and narrower body in the middle, optionally surrounded by other divs.