# CKEditor Stripping Out Some of Our CSS classes

Tags: ckeditor

We are having a problem with CKEditor (ver 4.1.1.5) stripping out some of our css classes when we are editing in the FULL HTML mode using SOURCE. From looking at some of the other questions posed on this, the Advanced Content Filter is the place we should be going. And, if I read this correctly, we need to edit the config.js file to add: CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent=true;

Am I going in the right direction? I want the WYSIWYG to still work for people with no html experience. However, when we go into source, I want all classes to remain and not be stripped out, no matter what.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CKEditor automatically strips classes from div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659390/ckeditor-automatically-strips-classes-from-div)

Answer (score 2):

You are partially right:

- Yes, Advanced Content Filter (ACF) is the mechanism responsible for this.
- But no, setting `config.allowedContent` to `true` is not a correct solution.

In short, ACF is a useful mechanism that lets you easily control the content that your users add to your site with CKEditor. Instead of disabling it, however, you should extend the filter configuration to accept whatever additional elements, classes, styles, attributes you want to allow.

In your case, if you want to [additionally allow](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraAllowedContent) all classes for all elements, use this in your [editor configuration](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration):

```
config.extraAllowedContent = '*(*)';
```

Read more about ACF here:

- [Content Filtering (ACF)](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf) - introduction
- Demo of [Automatic Mode](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/acf.html) and [Custom Mode](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/acfcustom.html)
- [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) - more advanced
- [Allowed Content Rules](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules) - syntax for ACF rules

Comment: Now, we want to only allow this in our Full HTML setup, which is only available to us developers. We don't want this for our Filtered HTML which we make available to our content producers. So, is this still the right thing to add to our editor's configuration?

Comment: Anna, please see my comment in the next "Answer."

Comment: Then you should use this configuration setting for the Full HTML setup only.

Comment: I had to do both. `config.allowedContent = true` and `config.allowedContent = true;`