# CKEditor 4 in read only mode - removing buttons removes formatting

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I use CKEditor to allow my users to create a rich document which I then want to redisplay inside a CKEditor instance to other users.

I want to simply display the content so I make the control read only but I don't want all the toolbars showing.

If I use removeButtons or any of the other methods to remove these disabled toolbars then I also lose the formatting associated with those buttons. Eg. If I remove the underline button I lose underline formatting in the content.

Is there a way to hide these buttons without losing the formatting in the content?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CKEditor automatically strips classes from div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659390/ckeditor-automatically-strips-classes-from-div)

Answer (score 1):

That is standard CK behaviour as stated in the [ACF documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter).
When you don't set the allowed content CK binds it to the toolbars in the editor, so removing the buttons will make ACF strip any HTML that would be created by such buttons.

The solution is, in your read-only editors, set `CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent` to allow all the tags you'll be displaying.

Comment: This should have been accepted, I had the same problem and by setting `allowedContent` to `true` I had my tags back!