# CKEditor automatically strips All div and classes and attribute

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am working on `Ckeditor` and `Ckfinder` in codeigniter framework  When I upload the HTML and go to the source code all div tag strips as well as all classes strips.

I already changes in **config.js** file

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

But it does not changes any thing. and I also confuse in **config.js** i got 
**ckeditor/config.js** file which has a one function `CKEDITOR.editorConfig()`.

This is right file? and What to do for this Situation.

Comment: this may help you..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659390/ckeditor-automatically-strips-classes-from-div

Answer (score 0):

You can allow content with your **ckeditor/config.js** file.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
    // other config items
    config.extraAllowedContent = 'div(*)';
};
```