# CKEditor :: Wrap content by custom tag

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I wrote a plugin for CKEditor.I want to wrap contents of editor between `div` with custom style.

In this case I used `dialog` for style `div` tag. How can I wrap contents of editor inside `div` :

```
  onOk: function() {
            var dialog = this;
            var color = dialog.getValueOf('tab1', 'color');
            // other styles
            var tag= '<div style="';
            tag += 'color:' + color + ';';
            // ... other styles
            tag += '">';
            // tag += contents ;
            tag += "</div>";
            editor.insertHtml(tag)
        },
        contents: [{ ...
```

Comment: How about creating  a div using document.createElement and setting its innerHTML to CKEDITOR.instances.name_of_editor.getData();

Comment: thanks, I found the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution :

first in `config.js` put the below line :

```
config.allowedContent = 'div{*}'; // this is important
```

see [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659390/ckeditor-automatically-strips-classes-from-div/15659962#15659962).

then in `onOk` function do this :

```
   onOk: function() {
            contents = editor.document.getBody().getHtml(); // get the content of CKEditor
            var dialog = this;
            var color = dialog.getValueOf('tab1', 'color');
            // other styles
            var tag= '<div style="';
            tag += 'color:' + color + ';';
            // ... other styles
            tag += '">';
            tag += contents ;
            tag += "</div>";
            editor.setData(tag);
        },
        contents: [{ ...
```