# ck_editor doesn't load real data

Tags: php, html, ckeditor

Why doesn't the ck editor load the last change that I made in source mode?
If I have disabled the ck_editor, then the textarea will show all the data.
This is my code:

```
<textarea name="content" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
   <?php print $selecteddata['content']; ?>
</textarea>

<script>
       // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
       // instance, using default configuration.

       CKEDITOR.replace( 'content' ,{
          filebrowserBrowseUrl : './public/browse.php',
          filebrowserUploadUrl : '/uploader/index.php',
          uiColor : '#9AB8F3'
      });

</script>
```

Comment: lemme to explain more, i have a page for updating data  so in this page i retrive data from db and then i will  put it in textarea  as u can see in above code and then i try to change the data in source code mode and after submit the database update the data as well but after reload this update page dk ediotr doesn't show the last change that i did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was about CKEditor Data Filtering and Features Activation .

the answer was here.
[CKEditor automatically strips classes from div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659390/ckeditor-automatically-strips-classes-from-div#)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<textarea name="content" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
      <?php print $selecteddata['content']; ?>
</textarea>

<script>
   $(window).load(function(){
      if (typeof(CKEDITOR.instances['content'])=='undefined') {
          CKEDITOR.replace( 'content',{
            filebrowserBrowseUrl : './public/browse.php',
            filebrowserUploadUrl : '/uploader/index.php',
            uiColor : '#9AB8F3'
         });
     }
  });
</script>
```