# How to completely disable auto changes in ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I want to use <(label)> tag as well as class="" attribute in <(span)>  margin-left (property in span) tag but ckeditor automatic replace label tag and class from span and it also remove margin property from style attribute in span tag

Answer (score 1):

Ckeditor apply ACF (Advanced Content Filter) by default. If you don't want to apply this you can disable by add this in your config file :

```
CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true
```

This will allow all type of input into your editor. You can read more detail [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter).

Answer (score 0):

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'styles', groups: [ 'styles' ] },
        { name: 'colors', groups: [ 'colors' ] },
        '/',
        { name: 'links', groups: [ 'links' ] },
        { name: 'insert', groups: [ 'insert' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'blocks' ] },
        { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode' ] }
    ];

    config.removeButtons = 'Save,NewPage,Preview,Print,PasteText,PasteFromWord,Find,Replace,Scayt,SelectAll,Form,Checkbox,Radio,TextField,Textarea,Select,Button,ImageButton,HiddenField,Outdent,Indent,CreateDiv,JustifyLeft,JustifyCenter,JustifyRight,JustifyBlock,Subscript,Superscript,Strike,BidiLtr,BidiRtl,Language,Anchor,Flash,Table,HorizontalRule,PageBreak,Iframe,Styles,Format,Font,Maximize,ShowBlocks,About,SpecialChar,Templates';
    config.extraAllowedContent = 'label';// This will allow label tag..

};
```

You have to edit config.js file.

Comment: I had tried config.allowedContent = true in my project but it was not working for me. You check this link to know more about adding attributes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659390/ckeditor-automatically-strips-classes-from-div

Answer (score 0):

CKEDITOR version 4

```
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty.i = 0;
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty.span = 0;
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty.figure = 0; ...etc any tag
```