# copy from webpages or word to ckeditor all tags and style intact

Tags: ckeditor

I 'm doing to copy web pages or Word documents to CKEditor.
but with the config below some tags, for example span dispear.

How to make all tags and attributes and styles intact?

I use CKEditor 4.

Here's the config.

```
config.forcePasteAsPlainText = false;
config.pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles = false;
config.pasteFromWordRemoveStyles = false;
config.allowedContent = true;
```

Comment: Possibly related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15659390/1586231)?

Answer (score 0):

You might also check [`config.pasteFromWordCleanupFile`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-pasteFromWordCleanupFile), which defaults to `<plugin path> + 'filter/default.js'`. If you have modified the default.js file, or are pointing to another cleanup filter file, that might cause your issues.

Comment: In my case I use the default settings. and added the above in the question.

Comment: All I want is just span tags and there style attributes.