# Why is span with class not showing up in WYSIWYG mode

Tags: html, css, ckeditor, dotnetnuke, wysiwyg

When I use this HTML code:

```
<p><span class>test</span></p>
```

And I go to WYSIWYG mode, it is invisible.

When I go into Inspect Element, is see this output:

```
<p><!--{cke_protected}%3Cspan%20class%3Etest%3C%2Fspan%3E--></p>
```

Is this a configuration setting?

Let me know please.

Thanks in advance!

Edit 1:

At first I had

```
<p><span class="classname">test</span></p>
```

But then I figured out that it has nothing to do with the class itself, but just using the attribute "class" is enough to get it invisible.

Also, it is only happening with a span, the others are working...

Comment: ckeditor has here: http://ckeditor.com/features a online window where I tried this. If I copy/paste your html into the "source" and go to wysiwyg mode I still see it.

Comment: Yes, I see. But when you go back to code mode, you see that it removed the whole span and just leaves the <p>test</p>. Is it some configuration or so?

Comment: Try setting `config.allowedContent = true;` work? Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659390/ckeditor-automatically-strips-classes-from-div

Comment: It is not that it's stripping my classes. It does add the span with the class but it is just not visible in the WYSIWYG mode. (config.allowContent = true was already configured!)

Answer (score 0):

That is because you don't have the correct syntax for HTML.
Try this instead:

```
<p><span class="">test</span></p>
```

Comment: Is doesn't matter if I use ="" or not. As soon as the word 'class' is included, is it invisible.

Comment: What if you put an actual class into the quotes?

Comment: The same thing happens. At first I had class="classname", then I found out that it has nothing to do with the class itself but the attribute "class" is enough to get it invisible