# Is it possible to use Mutation Observer with CKEditor? How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I'm trying to notice changes in the present CKEditor's content. My intention is to check which element has it's content changed. Assuming the user is writing several paragraphs, I want to be able to know which paragraph the user has changed.

I'm not an expert on JavaScript nor jQuery. After searching a bit, I ended up writing the following code:

```
var docWrapper = editor.document;   // [object Object] CKEditor object
var documentNode = docWrapper.$;    // [object HTMLDocument] DOM object

var paras = documentNode.getElementsByTagName('p');

for(var c = 0 ; c < paras.length ; c++)
{
    // Set up action to be done.
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) 
    {
        console.log('Im getting called!');

        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) 
        {
            console.log('Type: ' + mutation.type);
        });    
    });

    // Set up configurations.
    var config = { 
            attributes : true , 
            childList : true , 
            characterData : true ,
            subtree: true,
            characterDataOldValue : true
    };

    // Register everything up.
    observer.observe(paras[c] , config);
}
```

This line:

```
console.log('Im getting called!');
```

Is never getting called. Could someone help me with this, please? If any additional details are needed, please comment and I will edit my question.

Here's a JSFiddle that I was playing around:

https://jsfiddle.net/ej22k4vn/2/

Thank you.

### EDIT

Just wanted to share the solution, thanks to karthick. Here's the final JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('text-area-editor');

  // Stops CKEditor content filtering (not recommended).
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659390/ckeditor-automatically-strips-classes-from-div
    editor.config.allowedContent = true;

    /*
     * this line is required then only you can access the instance using 
     * editor.document
     */
    CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev)
    {
        init();
    });

    function init()
    {
        var documentWrapper = editor.document;      // [object Object] CKEditor object
        var documentNode = documentWrapper.$;       // [object HTMLDocument] DOM object
        var paras = documentNode.getElementsByTagName('p');

        for (var c = 0; c < paras.length; c++)
        {
            // Set up action to be done.
            // mutationRecords = Object vector of type MutationRecord.
            // obs = Observer instance.
      // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver
            var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutationRecords , obs)
            {
                console.log('Im getting called!');

                mutationRecords.forEach(function(mutation)
                {
                    console.log('Type: ' + mutation.type);
                    console.log('ID: ' + mutation.target.getAttribute('id'));
                    console.log('Class: ' + mutation.target.className);
                });
            });

            // Set up configurations.
            var config =
            {
                attributes : true,
                childList : true,
                characterData : true,
                subtree : true,
                characterDataOldValue : true
            };

            // Register everything up.
            observer.observe(paras[c], config);
        }
    };
});
```

And here's a JSFiddle working example. Please, take a look, everything is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/ej22k4vn/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait till your instance is active. You can check when your instance is up by listening to 'instanceReady' event.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('text-area-editor');
/*
 * this line is required then only you can access the instance using 
 * editor.document
 */
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev ) { 
    init();
});
function init() {

var documentWrapper = editor.document; // [object Object] ... CKEditor object
var documentNode = documentWrapper.$; // [object HTMLDocument] .... DOM object
var paras = documentNode.getElementsByTagName('p');

  for(var c = 0 ; c < paras.length ; c++)
  {
      // Set up action to be done.
      var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) 
      {
          console.log('Im getting called!');

          mutations.forEach(function(mutation) 
          {
              console.log('Type: ' + mutation.type);
          });    
      });

      // Set up configurations.
      var config = { 
              attributes : true , 
              childList : true , 
              characterData : true ,
              subtree: true,
              characterDataOldValue : true
      };

      // Register everything up.
      observer.observe(paras[c] , config);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you! You just saved my day! Thank you, really! :)