# Why does the CKEditor5 filter out my content (styles, classes, elements)?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5

I am using CKEditor5 as editor on my website. When I switch the "source button" and paste my html code, then toggle back the source button - my html code has changed and I am missing some class and html tags.
As example, paste this

```
<div class="myclass">some content</div>
```

it has been changed to...

```
<p>some content</p>
```

This question was asked 9 years ago and was related to Version 4.
[CKEditor automatically strips classes from div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659390/ckeditor-automatically-strips-classes-from-div)
Solution was an additional parameter

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

but looks to me, it is not working any longer.
The CKEditor5 FAQ says, I have to write a plugin.
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/support/faq.html#why-does-the-editor-filter-out-my-content-styles-classes-elements-where-is-configallowedcontent-true

Does anyone has done this?
Or is there an easier solution?

Answer (score 1):

CKEditor 5 filters out everything that its included features do not support. In other words, CKE5 supports only those that you added as plugins.

If none of features work with `<div>`, it will be removed during conversion to internal modal. See upcast/downcast convertors and dataSchema.

To start working with `div`, you either

1. have to add any feature (aka plugin) that works with it and registers required explicit up/down conversions via a model.
2. OR add raw HTML support via [GeneralHTMLSupport](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/html/general-html-support.html#configuration) plugin.

```
const htmlSupport = {
    allow: [
        {
            name: 'div',
            classes: ['myclass'],
        },
    ],
};
```

The key to undertand about internals is that all incoming data goes through conversions, hence, if something is not supported by convertors, it will be stripped out.

Answer (score 0):

check these documents:

[migration-guide](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/migration-from-ckeditor-4.html#configuration-options-compatibility-table) and [general-html-support](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/html/general-html-support.html)

Basically, their FAQ is not really straightforward answering about filtering out those elements and should link these pages above that I sent you, as CKEditor 5 works completely different from CKEditor 4.

But you could achieve that by installing `GeneralHtmlSupport` from `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-html-support`

Hope it helps :)